# Efficient way to solve subset sum variation

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, subset-sum

Given an integer array, find the maximum number of sums of **adjacent** elements that are divisible by `n`.

Example 1:

`input: long[] array = [1, 2, 3]`, `n = 7`

`output: 0`

Example 2:

`input: long[] array = [1, 2, 4]`, `n = 7`

`output: 1`

Example 3:

`input: long[] array = [2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]`, `n = 4`

`output: 6`

Constraints:

`array.length = 50000`

`array[index] <= 2^31 - 1`

`n <= 2^31 - 1`

Currently, this is my code:

```
public static int maxSums(long[] array, long n) {

        int count = 0;

        if (array.length == 1 && array[0] == n) {
            return 1;
            
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                long sum = 0;
                for (int j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
                    sum += array[j];
                    if (sum % n == 0) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
```

which is essentially the window sliding technique. However, this code runs with time complexity `O(n^2)` which is pretty slow, and results in `Apex CPU Time Limit Exceeded` towards the higher end of the constraints. Is there a faster way to solve this?

Comment: Since you need *"sums of **adjacent** elements"* then output in the example `3` should be **4**, not **6**. Because there are only **4** adjacent combinations which can give the sum of `4`: `1,2,1`, `2,1,1`, `1,1,2`, `1,2,1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach I just thought of is `O(n*m)`, where `n` is the actual `n` parameter and `m` is the array length.

The algorithm remembers for every subsequence up to the current index what reminder the sequence sum has. This information is stored inside the array called `currentMod`.

When iterating over the input array this `currentMod` is updated. We simply add to each possible modulo value of iteration `i-1` the value of the input array at index `i`. The updated array includes the number of subsequence sums ending at index `i` for each possible reminder: `0`, `1`, `2` up to `n-1`.

The element first element of `tmpMod` at index `i` includes the number of subsequences that end at index `i` and have a sum divisible by `n`. Therefore, we add them to our final result.

Here is the algorithm:

```
public static int maxSums(int[] array, int n) {
    int[] currentMod = new int[n];
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Add +1 to 0 remainder as a new sequence can start at every index which has sum 0
        currentMod[0] += 1;
        
        int[] tmpMod = new int[n];

        for (int j = 0; j < currentMod.length; j++) {
            // For every subsequence reminder of i-1 calculate the reminders of adding element i to every subsequence
            tmpMod[(j + array[i]) % n] += currentMod[j];
        }

        // Add number of subsequence sums that divide by n with remainder 0 to result 
        count += tmpMod[0];
        
        currentMod = tmpMod;
    }

    return count;
}
```

P.S.: This algorithm is not strictly better/worse than yours. It depends on another input value. This means it depends on your inputs what is more efficient. My algorithm is only better for a case with large arrays and low `n` values.

**EDIT:** After a lot of thinking and testing I think I found a good solution. It is `O(n)` in time complexity. It is also `O(n)` in space complexity as there can be at most `n` different remainders with `n` values in the array.

The algorithm keeps track of the current remainder, which is dividable by the input `n` from the start. For each new subsequence, we add the `1` at the current remainder. In this way, we already define which total sum (`mod n`) we need that the subsequence is dividable by `n`.

```
public static int maxSums(int[] array, int n) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> currentMod = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int count = 0;
    int currentZero = 0;

    for (int val : array) {
        currentMod.put(currentZero, currentMod.getOrDefault(currentZero, 0) + 1);

        currentZero = (currentZero + val) % n;

        count += currentMod.getOrDefault(currentZero, 0);
    }

    return count;
}
```

Also, some comparisons to show that it should work out:

`len(array)=50000` and `n=1000`:

- Your method: 11704 ms
- My old one: 188 ms
- My new one: 13 ms

`len(array)=50000` and `n=1000000`:

- Your method: 555 ms
- My old one: stopped after 2 minutes
- My new one: 6 ms

Comment: thank you for the response. unfortunately, the question has some interesting constraints (which I initially forgot to add, sorry) that neither of our codes can meet on the higher end, as you have mentioned.

Comment: I see. With these constraints, your solution is definitely better. Is there also a constraint for the elements inside the input array or are they some random integers?

Comment: fairly certain they share the same parameters as n. have added them into the question. thank you for clarifying

Comment: Please, see my edit I think I found the solution. Not an easy puzzle :P

Comment: very insightful. indeed, tackling time complexity for code efficiency purposes is a difficult task, since a solution to solve the problem is already planted in my head and it's hard to deviate from it. thank you very much.